# Water Leak 2003 Ford Focus sedan

Tags: ford, focus, trunk

I noticed water inside the trunk saturating the carpet  & went into spare tire wheel well. This morning I discovered a puddle of water in the rear drivers side floor saturating the carpet.

I initially thought the leak was from pine needle debris clogging up the trunk door area - see pics:

[image]

but it seems unlikely.

How do I diagnose the source of the leak & how do I fix it? 
Are there known water leak issues with this 1st Gen Focus models?

Answer (score 2):

The most cost effective method is to climb in the trunk and close the lid. Have a friend spray the trunk area with a garden hose. Concentrate the water at the rear window edges and the trunk lid weather seal. Usually if water is getting into the back seat it is the rear glass seal that is leaking. The leak may be from the seal between the glass and the car body or rust.

Answer (score 0):

Another common source of leaks is around the rear lamps, I realise this is probably not the source of the water in the rear driver's side floor, but could be relevant for the back... good luck...